# PCI Express BAR memory mapping basic understanding

Tags: memory, pci-express, pci, memory-management, dma

I am trying to understand how PCI Express works so i can write a windows driver that can read and write to a custom PCI Express device with no on-board memory.

I understand that the Base Address Registers (BAR) in the PCIE configuration space hold the memory address that the PCI Express should respond to / is allowed to write to. (Is that correct understood?)

My questions are the following:

- What is a "bus-specific address" compared to physical address when talking about PCIE?
- When and how is the BAR populated with addresses? Is the driver responsible for allocating memory and writing the address to the peripheral BAR?
- Can the addresses in BAR be changed in run-time?
- Is DMA used when transferring data from peripheral to host memory?

I appreciate your time.

Best regards,

Comment: Questions about drive responsibilities are specific to each operating system. Also, when you use the term "driver", you should clarify which driver you mean. (I'm assuming you mean the driver for the specific device.)

Comment: Hello David - Yes i ofcourse mean the specific device driver for that particuly PCIe device.